# $(this) equivalent in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm working on a very simple application.

I have a form with a bunch of boxes.

When I hover any one of these boxes, I want to call the method `SwapImage();` which just changes the background image.

How can I can I get this to change, with out specifying control I want to change. In jQuery(not that these are comparable by any means), I would use $(this), what is the equivalent of that in C#?

```
private void SwapImage(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    sender.BackColor = Color.Coral;
    MessageBox.Show("What are you doing, you should be working!");
}
```

Comment: What is the type of the box? You need to cast `sender` to that type and it will work

Comment: are you familiar with how to cast the Sender..?

Comment: You're just missing a cast.  What are your boxes?  Panels?  PictureBoxes?

Comment: Picture boxes, and I am not familiar with cast sender, I will read up. Thanks

Comment: Why the down votes? Is this really that bad of a question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There *isn't* a particular equivalent of `$(this)` in C#, but in the current context, it seems that you have an event handler, where `sender` is the object raising the event. You can cast it to your type and then change the property. Suppose your `Box` is a `PictureBox` then in that case you can do:

```
private void SwapImage(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PictureBox pictureBox = sender as PictureBox;
    if (pictureBox != null)
    {
        pictureBox.BackColor = Color.Coral;
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("What are you doing, you should be working!");
    }
}
```